# Tant pis ou tampis ?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe

Je me posais une question à propos de « Tant pis » et « Tampis »

Quelles sont les étymologies de ces deux expressions respectives ?

***Question:*** Il semble que cette expression soit beaucoup plus utilisée à l'oral qu'à l'écrit. Pourquoi ?

**edit: il existe bien des écrit utilisant "tampis", voir la réponse de `jlliagre` pour plus de détails**

Comment: "*tampis* n'existe pas. Tu as cherché sur google avant ? Il y a [tout ce qu'il faut](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/orthographe/tampis-tant-pis-orthographe/).

Comment: Ce n'est pas moi qui ai voté, mais en général la question est moins bien reçue si c'est quelque chose qu'on peut trouver facilement sur google. Est-ce que tu as cherché ? Quel est l'état de tes recherches, ou est-ce que tu bloques ?

Comment: *Tampis* est bien plus utilisé à l'écrit que je ne le pensais initialement. La question mériterait d'être rouverte.

Comment: La question demande juste l'orthographe et l'étymologie d'un mot. En principe un dictionnaire devrait donner la réponse. Quels dictionnaires as-tu consulté ? En quoi leur contenu est-il insuffisant ? La question n'a d'intérêt que si les dictionnaires usuels ne donnent pas l'information cherchée, et ceci ne me paraît pas être le cas.

Comment: @Gilles Je pense bien que vous n'avez pas pris le temps de lire entièrement ma question, car il est écrit *Il semble que cette expression soit beaucoup plus utilisée à l'oral qu'à l'écrit. Pourquoi ?* C'est ce point là que je souhaite éclaircir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le mot ***<s>tampis</s>*** n'existe pas<sup>1</sup>, mais sa prononciation serait exactement la même, ce qui peut surprendre un non francophone.

Il faut écrire ***tant pis***, locution qui signifie *c'est dommage, c'est regrettable, mais c'est comme ça*. C'est l'inverse de ***tant mieux*** qui signifie *c'est préférable, c'est une bonne nouvelle*.

***Tant*** est synonyme d'**autant** et ***pis*** est une survivance assez unique en français du genre neutre du latin (cf. ***pire***) que l'on retrouve dans *de mal en pis*, *pis aller* ou *pis que pendre*.

*Tant pis* est plus utilisé à l'oral qu'à l'écrit car il exprime souvent une opinion dans un dialogue.

---

<sup>1</sup> Plus précisément, il n'est pas répertorié dans les dictionnaires, ou alors en tant que [faute de français](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/tampis/fr-fr/). Il apparaît néanmoins sporadiquement dans quelques écrits, souvent anciens, et assez fréquemment dans des forums et autres sites en ligne. On peut supposer que c'est essentiellement par méconnaissance de la graphie correcte mais il y a certainement des cas où c'est volontaire.

Voici quelques occurrences de ce ***tampis*** qui n'existe pas :

Charles Philipon, *LA CARICATURE MORALE, RELIGIEUSE, LITTÉRAIRE ET SCÉNIQUE*,  1830

[image]

On trouve même ***tampis*** et ***tampire*** chez Marivaux, *l’Épreuve*, 1758 :

[image]